# Intellisense in .aspx for new tags added to the web.config pages/controls element

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, intellisense

When I add an element in the `controls` node, the `.aspx` doesn't reflect it immediately. Often, down the road in the development, it will show up (when I could have used it before).

Obviously Visual Studio uses a cache somewhere. How do I refresh that cache so I can get intellisense in the `.aspx` for properties and what not?

```
  <pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.DomainServices.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.DomainServices.WebControls"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [adding the assemblies in the Web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1.aspx) too (assuming it is a different assembly to your main one):

```
<add assembly="System.Web.DomainServices.WebControls, Version=...."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you will be getting errors in the code behind. Comment the code causing error. Build the solution.Then uncomment the code. Build the solution. See whether it is working